# How do I run a build for a single workspace using pnpm?

Tags: pnpm

I am trying to use [a repo that uses pnpm](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter). I have used workspaces before on npm and yarn, but am not familiar with pnpm.

The repo organises it's workspaces two levels beneath `packages`, ie in this case I want to run the `build` script on [the package in `packages/starter/example`](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter/example)

[Reading the pnpm docs](https://pnpm.io/filtering), I believe this should be:

```
pnpm --filter packages/starter/example run build
```

Which fails with:

```
pnpm --filter packages/starter/example run build
No projects matched the filters in "/home/me/myproject"
```

But I can see the directory is correct:

```
$ ls packages/starter/example/
CHANGELOG.md  LICENSE  README.md  next-env.d.ts  next.config.js  node_modules  package.json  public  src  tsconfig.json
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to filter by path, you need to either prefix the path with `./`:

```
pnpm --filter ./packages/starter/example run build
```

or place it inside `{}`:

```
pnpm --filter "{packages/starter/example}" run build
```

Answer (score 4):

**Adding my own answer to help others:**

It looks like the filter uses the packages `name` (as defined in `package.json`) rather than its workspace directory.

Eg following the `name` from `packages/starter/example/package.json`:

```
pnpm --filter "@solana/wallet-adapter-example" build
```